# Transform coordinates in csv file from wgs84 to nad27 using qgis

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv

I've got a .csv file which lists boreholes and their x & y coordinate information in NAD27. I was wondering if there is a way to use QGIS when transforming the coordinate information into WGS84. The desired end product would be a .csv file where all boreholes are specified in the wgs84 system.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your file using the CSV reader (look for the comma icon on the left) and then select the new layer, right click and choose `save as`. Then pick csv as your output format. Type a new file name in, change the CRS drop down to WGS84 (EPSG:4326), and then scroll down the page to GEOMETRY and select `AS_XY` and then click OK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, the new x/y values in the first two columns are the exact copies of the values which had to be transformed... The crs of the project is nad72 and I imported the csv file as nad72 also. On the fly transformation is also turned off. I think I am doing something wrong when importing the csv file, could there be a problem around there?

Comment: The values in the attribute table won't change with reprojecting. After reprojecting, you have to add new fields of type real and precision greater than zero with `$x` and `$y` as field content. Note that reprojecting NAD27 to WGS84 may not work outside of USA and Canada.

Comment: When I do this I end up with new cols x_1 and y_1 with the old values in and new values in x & y. There may not be much change with NAD72 to WGS84 depending on where your data is

Comment: BTW make sure to put latitudes in Y and western longitudes with negative sign in X.